# Golf Round Recorder PHP, MYSQL, AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am developing a golf website where users can track their rounds and handicaps and have a few different ideas on how the user inputs their round information.  I have a table for courses and a corresponding row in another table (scorecards) that has all the courses scorecard information.  The 'round recorder' is a three part form (basic, scorecard, preferences) and in the basic part of the form the course input is a autocomplete field.  I was wondering if there was a way that I could use a chained select from a autocomplete field.

e.x. Course1(has 18 holes) -> List Front Nine/Back Nine (user selects one or both and than loads that scorecard from database)

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey Nick, i'm actually working on something similar. Is it a hobby project or are you developing a product?

Comment: This is just a hobby project.  What about you?

Comment: Same here. I'm good with backend stuff like DB storage but the frontend part is a new frontier :P

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the most specific answer, but basically you want to capture the "change" event of the select box. For the front or back nine, you would check whether "front", "back", or both was checked and update that accordingly within load_scorecard().

```
<select onchange="load_scorecard(this.value);">
```

and then the JS:

```
function load_scorecard(scorecard_id) {
    // Obtain data from a database or preloaded array
    // Then, update the page with the scorecard.
}
```

Comment: I first needed to pull the information from the course input (which is a text field) and return the user options of what course they played in a check box i.e. Front Nine, Back Nine, Red Course etc. and than once the user checks the courses he played it would direct to scorecard part.